# Using google maps in an android/ios application

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I would like to use google maps in an android and ios application and I don't understand whether or not I have to pay to use it? I would like the app to have only search by address and the location of the user.

I have looked into https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/ but I still don't know for sure if I will have to pay if the app will have more users... it will be a free app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> search by address uses the *Google Places API*

Default 1,000 free requests per day, increased to 150,000 free requests per day after credit card validation.

> location of the user can be find by the *Google Maps API*

Unlimited free usage.